# Problem Django: Needs rebuild when i make HTML changes

Tags: python, django, pycharm, rebuild

The problem is as follows:
If I make changes to `HTML / CSS`, I have to re-build the project (django) so that I can refresh at DOM. If I make changes to the `.py` files, it is rebuilt automatically.

What can I do to rebuild them automatically when I make changes to `HTML / CSS`?

*rebuild = python manage.py runserver*

to be updated i need to make rebuild like in the image: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVvV1.png)

#### Solved. Solution? `django-livereload-server` (https://github.com/tjwalch/django-livereload-server)

Comment: What do you mean by rebuilding ? Restarting the django server ?

Comment: yes. python manage.py runserver.

Comment: Try doing a hard refresh, `Ctrl + Shift + R` in windows or `Cmd + Shift + R` in mac. This could be due to caching of the website by your browser.

Comment: yes, i try. No changes.

Comment: Definitely a caching issue. Try opening the project in incognito/private browsing.

Comment: btw, check this image: https://imgur.com/a/vColpvp, soo. the red text was when i refresh the page.

Comment: @Anthony no changes... so to make the DOM updated i need to rebuild like in the image: https://imgur.com/a/9czLtep

Comment: Try running the server from command prompt rather than pycharm console and see if that helps.

Comment: @Anthony don't working, because need a build. https://imgur.com/a/xMKLoAq

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using HTML/CSS as the Templates, a simple refresh must do the trick. If it doesn't work, try `Clear Cache + Hard Reload`
On Chrome: Ctrl + Shift + I to open Dev Tools, right-click the reload button and select the option.

Comment: Nop, doesn't work. Check the image. I need a rebuild (python manage.py runserver) to work. How can i make the "python manage.py runserver" every time when i make changes to html with f5?